# Hadoop Hive get position from array

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm using the array_contains function to find items in an array, and it works well.  What I'm looking for a returning the index of the array in which there was a match.

```
 select b.sku_id
 ,array_position(b.sku_list, b.sku_id) as matched_index
 from
 (select split(the_list, ',') as sku_list, sku_id
 from data_table) b
 where array_contains(b.sku_list, b.sku_id) = TRUE;
```

This is where my error is:

```
,array_position(b.sku_list, b.sku_id) as matched_index
```

The reason that is the error is there is no built-in UDF for array_position in Hive.  Any solutions to get the index of the matched value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no index of UDF supported natively by hive.

However, Brickhouse have an [array index of](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayIndexOfUDF.java) UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hive-third-functions](https://github.com/aaronshan/hive-third-functions). It provide `array_position` and other many array functions.